# How to replace domain's model usage by view model efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I keep seeing that using the domain model directly as a parameter to a view is bad practice. But doing otherwise seems overly complicated and error prone. Example:

Here's a view to edit an `ItemViewModel`:

```
@model ItemViewModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>

    @Html.LabelFor(o => o.ItemId) : @Html.EditorFor(o => o.ItemId)      
    @Html.LabelFor(o => o.MyItemProperty) : @Html.EditorFor(o => o.MyItemProperty)
}
```

And here are the controller methods to handle this

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id) 
{
    Item itemViewModel = new ItemViewModel();

    if (id != null && id != 0)
    {
        var item = itemRepository.Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        if (item != null)
        {
            itemViewModel.ItemId = item.ItemId;
            itemViewModel.MyItemProperty = item.ItemId;
        }
    }

    return View(itemViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ItemViewModel itemViewModel)
{
    var item = itemRepository.Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == itemViewModel.Id);
    item.Id = itemViewModel.Id;
    item.MyItemProperty = itemViewModel.MyItemProperty;
    itemRepository.Save(item);

    return View("Success");
}
```

That means that I have to convert `Item` to `ItemViewModel` to `Item` again. And if I add a new property to `Item` and I forget to add it the conversion, I will end up with changes not saved.

Is this how you do it or did I miss something?

Comment: In a nutshell, that's it.  You could look into [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or something similar, or write your own extension methods for mapping if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.  I would convert from Item to ItemModel to Item as you have queried above.  And then have another class called SomethingRelevantViewModel that has your ItemModel as a property and is the @model for the View.  Then you can essentially attach many different SomethingModels to a View or Lists of SomethingsModels for DropDowns, Grids, etc.

The real magic of your ItemModel will be when you add DataAnnotations, which it looks like you may be using since your are using LabelFor.  You can also use DataAnnotations for required and more complicated things.

We often use data first Entity Framework and cheat by copy-pasting the T4 auto generated classes as our starting point for a SomethingModel.  There are many ways to make this process fast.